# Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource

Tags: kubernetes

I tried to create a new pod:

```
kubectl apply -f first-pod.yaml
```

Facing an issue:
[image]

I have installed new version of kubectl 1.17:

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.17.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe
```

Installed version check:

[image]

404 error with kubectl apply -f first-pod.yaml -v=8:
[image: img3]

Answer (score 0):

> **[kubectl is supported within one minor version](https://v1-15.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/#kubectl)  (older or newer) of  `kube-apiserver`.**
> Example:
>
> - `kube-apiserver`  is at  **1.15**
> - `kubectl`  is supported at  **1.16**,  **1.15**, and  **1.14**
>
> Kubernetes versions are expressed as **x.y.z**, where **x** is the major version, **y** is the minor version, and **z** is the patch version.

Since your client is on version is 1.9.2 it's a huge version gap which can cause many issues.

**[This is the link to install the 1.15 kubectl version](https://v1-15.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/)** for Windows, Linux or MacOS.

If you need any further help just let me know!

Comment: Thanks you willrof. yes, as you said there is a huge difference with kube-apiserver. i struck with initial setup. could not able to upgrade to newer version. that why while apply command gets 404 issue due to that. i could not able to find where that kubectl version comes from. now the issue is resolved. Thanks for ur support

Comment: @user10134261If my answer was useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)"

Answer (score 0):

issue has resolved.
The problem is due to the version 1.9 , unable to set a new version even if i download it.
version 1.9 had installed along with docker installer very long back.

issue resolved by

- upgrading docker
- removed the path of docker
- download new kubectl , setting the path of new version & installed minikube
- set path of upgraded docker version.

[Kubectl version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb47w.png)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps kubectl cannot find the configuration file. First, you need to locate the configuration file by executing the command echo $KUBECONFIG on your server:

```bash
echo $KUBECONFIG
```

This will provide the path, for example:

```bash
/etc/k8s/kubectl/conf/kubectl.kubeconfig
```

Now, you can execute the following command:

```bash
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/k8s/kubectl/conf/kubectl.kubeconfig && kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```